# Chef uninitialized constant Chef::Recipe::AWS

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, chef-infra, aws-sdk

My cookbook is not compiling throwing the error **uninitialized constant Chef::Recipe::AWS.** The chef_gem aws-sdk installed fine, but still doesn't compile when **AWS.config(access_key_id: 'key', secret_access_key: 'pass')** is called.

```
chef_gem "aws-sdk"

AWS.config(access_key_id: key, secret_access_key: pass)

rds = AWS::RDS.new
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the doc from aws-sdk-ruby [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby) and to the code, the class name is `Aws` and not `AWS`.

But your main problem here is that you're not including the lib installed by the gem.

add `require 'aws-sdk'` before trying to call it's class.

To avoid being bitten by a name conflict with the `Chef::Recipe` namespace call the lib as a top level lib like `::Aws.config(...)`

Edit from personnal research:
`AWS` namespace is from the sdk v1, if you really wish to use this one and not the v2 you have to change your recipe to:

```
chef_gem "aws-sdk-v1"

require 'aws-sdk-v1'
AWS.config(access_key_id: key, secret_access_key: pass)

rds = AWS::RDS.new
```

Comment: This was the one that worked for me with my recipe. Using just the `require 'down'` didn't work. I had to make use of the `chef_gem "down" require 'down'` . I was getting the 'NameError uninitialized constant' even though the require loaded the gem. Many thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide to aws-sdk gem your aws credentials. As you can read in the gem documentation:

> Basic Configuration
>
> You need to provide your AWS security credentials and choose a default
>   region.
>
> AWS.config(access_key_id: '...', secret_access_key: '...', region:
>   'us-west-2')
>
> You can also specify these values via ENV:
>
> export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='...' export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='...'
>   export AWS_REGION='us-west-2'

Edit `'key'` and `'pass'` with your credentials, and add the aws region you want to use.

Comment: access_key_id and secret_access_key are set values, I just didn't show the variable declarations because obviously I don't want to show my credentials.

Comment: Ok, try adding `region` also.